# requests lib 403 status_code

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to implement simple api client and face pretty specific problem. Trying to make some simple requests in flat python code works just fine. But, when I am trying to wrap it all up into a small class it returns a response with `403` status code. I tried different ways to engage this problem, but so far nothing.

Snippet #1

```
import requests
import hashlib
import time

api_key = "my_api_key"
secret = "my_secret"
endpoint = "https://somecompany.com/some-api/1.0/status"

s = requests.Session()
s.headers['Accept'] = "application/json"
s.headers['Api-Key'] = api_key

def encode_signature(api_key, secret, time_secs):
    return hashlib.sha256(
        "{}{}{}".format(api_key, secret, time_secs)
        ).hexdigest()

def test_req(method, url, api_key, signature, **kwargs):
    r = requests.Request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
    prepped = s.prepare_request(r)
    prepped.headers['X-Signature'] = signature
    resp = s.send(prepped)
    return resp, prepped

if __name__ == '__main__':
    resp, req = test_req('GET', endpoint, api_key,
                         encode_signature(api_key, secret, int(time.time())))
    print resp.status_code
```

Snippet #2 (This one does not work, however it looks similar to me)

```
import requests
import hashlib
import time

api_key = "my_api_key"
secret = "my_secret"
endpoint = "https://somecompany.com/some-api/1.0/status"

class Transport(object):
    """docstring for Transport"""
    def __init__(self, api_key, secret):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.secret = secret
        self.conn = requests.Session()
        self.conn.headers['Api_Key'] = api_key
        self.conn.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'

    @property
    def signature(self):
        return hashlib.sha256(
        "{}{}{}".format(self.api_key, self.secret, int(time.time()))
        ).hexdigest()

    def request(self, method, endpoint, **kwargs):
        r = requests.Request(method=method, url=endpoint, **kwargs)
        prepped = self.conn.prepare_request(r)
        prepped.headers['X-Signature'] = self.signature
        resp = self.conn.send(prepped)
        return resp, prepped

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tr = Transport(api_key, secret)
    resp, req = tr.request('GET', endpoint)
    print resp.status_code
```

As I thought, I have done the exact same things with these two snippets with only difference: storing session in object attribute instead of global variable. Is there a way I handle the session object wrong? I am desperate for help!

Comment: In the `request()` function in the second snippet, change the line `prepped.headers['X-Signature'] = self.signature` to `... = self.signature()`, so it actually _calls_ the `signature()` method.

Comment: @martineau, `signature` is a property that returns string. I'm quite sure that `self.signature()` will lead to `TypeError`

Comment: Oops, sorry missed that. Humor me and see what happens if you remove the `@property` and explicitly call it like I suggested.

Comment: @martineau did try that, still the same

Comment: Hmm, well 403 means "Forbidden" but indicates that the server was reached and understood the request. I've seen this occassionally when requests were sent too frequently to a server. In other words, if you wait a while between attempts, it might work. Otherwise, I see nothing wrong with your class version.